# AngularJS $http.post how to set the json data into request body

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to send the post request with json data to server. But seems angularJS $http.post method does not set the data into body. How can I make it set the data into body?

The remote server is implemented use asp.net webapi and will read the data from body. so I need to set the json data into request body.

How can I implement this please? Thanks.

If the request send to same site, then it works. But if I send the request to CROS server, it does not work.

In the remote backend server, I already updated the webconfig to make it support CROS call, but it still does not work.

```
 $http.post(resourceUri, requestData)
    .success(function (response) {
    })
    .error(function (data, status, header, config) {
    });
```

Comment: Thanks all. I finally find out the root cause. This is caused by the CORS call, it required to configuration on remote server to support post CORS call.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

YOu can do it as follows
1. make a controller 
2. make a add data to the call

syntax for the post call is as follows

```
$http.post(url, data, [config])

app.controller('controller', function ($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        $http.post('url',data.call1($routeParams.id))
            .success(function (response) {
                 $scope.response = response;
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            });
    });


var data = {
    call1:
        function (value) {
            return {'key': value, 'key': 'some text'};
         }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried but it does not work. My code is $http.post(requestUri, dataObj) When track the request detail in fiddler, I find the request body is empty. The backend server is not same site with my application, This is CROS call, but my server already configured to support CROS call. Not sure how to make it works.

Comment: Thanks. $http.post(url, data, [config]) works, but required server side to configuration let it support CORS post call.

Answer (score 10):

You could build the request like this:

```
var req = {
 method: 'POST',
 url: 'http://example.com',
 headers: {
   'Content-Type': "application/json"
 },
 data: { test: 'test' }
}

$http(req).success(function(){...}).error(function(){...});
```

Comment: why Content-Type: `undefined`  ?  why not `application/x-www-form-urlencoded`  ?

Comment: ```undefined```?